# How to log Current username and time of editing of a cell and on multiple cell change in excel

Tags: excel, vba

My question is based on the follow up on the answer of Scott Holtzman(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman) here [Excel VBA - Insert Username ONLY when cell is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334444/excel-vba-insert-username-only-when-cell-is-changed)

The customised code is like this -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 2
        Dim sOld As String, sNew As String
        sNew = Target.Value 'capture new value

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .Undo
        End With

        sOld = Target.Value 'capture old value
        Target.Value = sNew 'reset new value

        If sOld <> sNew Then

            ' time stamp corresponding to cell's last update
            Range("BK" & ThisRow).Value = Now
            ' Windows level UserName | Application level UserName
            Range("BJ" & ThisRow).Value = Environ("username")
            Range("BJ:BK").EntireColumn.AutoFit

        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

So this code work flawlessly up until cells are changed one by one. But if someone pastes values in multiple cells at once the code throws a runtime error at the reset new value line.

I have this code also which works on multiple cell changes and logs the username and time but obviously, it can't compare whether the new value is changed or not so it updates the user & time with the current time and current user.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Adr As String

Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), Target)

xOffsetColumn = 1

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
        Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Environ("Username") & ", " & Now
End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

I want an amalgamation of the two that works even on pasting values in multiple cells in one go as well as compares the new values of those cells with their old values before assigning logs. Also if the new value is empty it appends the log value with the current user and time instead of replacing it.

I tried the second code mentioned above and it worked when pasting values in multiple cells. And it successfully stored logs in respective offset cells. But I couldn't get the comparison feature to work with that code.

Comment: The `Value` of a multi-cell range is a Variant array, not a string.  You will need to adjust your variable declarations so they're able to work with >1 cell, and then you'll need to loop over each cell in Target and compare the Old and New array values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim allOld, allNew, vOld, vNew, rng As Range, c As Range, i As Long
    Dim usr

    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("B"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no updates to process

    If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then 'doesn't handle non-contiguous updates
        MsgBox "multi-area updates can't be logged!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'On Error GoTo haveError
    
    'OK to proceed...
    allNew = ToArray(Target) 'entire update; ToArray() always reads an array...
    vNew = ToArray(rng)      'values of interest
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo         'revert to previous values
    
    vOld = ToArray(rng)      'previous values (Col B only)
    Target.Value = allNew    'reset Target value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vNew, 1)
        If vNew(i, 1) <> vOld(i, 1) Then
            If Len(usr) = 0 Then usr = Environ("username")
            rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Range("E1:F1").Value = Array(usr, Now)
        End If
    Next i
    
haveError:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure to re-enable
End Sub

'returns the value of both single cells and ranges as an array...
Function ToArray(rng As Range)
    Dim rv
    If rng.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ReDim rv(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        rv(1, 1) = rng.Value
        ToArray = rv
    Else
        ToArray = rng.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ok so first of all thanks. I tried the code and it fulfills two of the objectives. 1) It logs the Name and Time successfully in scenario where the pasted cells are contiguous. 2) It is able to compare the values individually for each of those cells and updates only corresponding cells that are changed. But what is still lacking is that 1) It doesn't work if the pasted cells are not contiguous. 2) It doesn't append the old values with new user and new time when a cell is deleted or cleared. (I know its easy to implement but your code is too hardcore for me to easily understand as a newbie).

Comment: It's considerably more complex to handle multi-area ranges.  As for appending the old values, why not try to adjust the code to do that?  That would be a relatively simple change.

Comment: As said I'm not a programmer. It'll be fun to tinker with your code, I'll give it a try.